# Bind ip problem in mongodb replication

Tags: mongodb

when iam doing mongodb v4.0.2 in ubuntu 16.04 i changed bind ip to 0.0.0.0 and but when iam trying to add nodes it shows error as;

```
  "errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must 
   be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2","code" : 
   103,"
```

and also rs.conf() shows even now the host as localhost:27017

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have configured replica set 
i) One server with 3 members
OR
ii) 3 server one for each member

If yor are running one server with 3 member follow the following steps
when you first fire rs.initiate() check hostname and port in the output of the following command.
and type that hostname with different port No. 
rs.add("hostname:port")

OR

If you are running 3 server one for each member steps are
1) Disable firewall
2) in config of mongod under net --> bindIP: 0.0.0.0
and then try to add member in the current replicaset.